Unexpected output on a function that counts days between 2 given dates
//A function that counts days from a given date to a given date
int count_days_from(int start_day, int start_month, int day, int month, int year){
    
    //DECLARATION AND INITIALIZATION SEGMENT
    int month_days[12] = {31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    int days = 0;

    //CALCULATIONS
    for(int i = start_month; i < month; i++)
        days = days + month_days[i];
    days = days + (month_days[month] - day);  
    
    
    return days;
}

Hello. This is something I coded in C in order to calculate the number of days between 2 given-from-user dates.
I tried to test it using the inputs printf("%d\n", count_days_from(1, 1, 31, 12, 2024);
Although there was the unexpected output: 1915424856
What is wrong with it?

Welcome!
I prefer that you calculate the days of the month and then calculate the days between the two dates.
The following code shows the best way to get the count days between two dates:
#include <stdio.h>

int getDaysInMonth(int year, int month) {
  if (month < 1 || month > 12) {
    printf("Invalid month: %d\n", month);
    return -1; // Indicate error
  }

  // Months with 31 days
  if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12) {
    return 31;
  }

  // February: check for leap year
  if (month == 2) {
    if (year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0)) {
      return 29;
    } else {
      return 28;
    }
  }

  // Months with 30 days (April, June, September, November)
  return 30;
}

bool isLeapYear(int year) {
  return (year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0));
}

int countDays(int startDate, int startMonth, int endDate, int endMonth, int year) {
  if (year < 1 || startMonth < 1 || startMonth > 12 || endMonth < 1 || endMonth > 12) {
    printf("Invalid year or month values\n");
    return -1; // Indicate error
  }

  if (startDate < 1 || startDate > getDaysInMonth(year, startMonth)) {
    printf("Invalid start day for month %d\n", startMonth);
    return -1; // Indicate error
  }

  if (endDate < 1 || endDate > getDaysInMonth(year, endMonth)) {
    printf("Invalid end day for month %d\n", endMonth);
    return -1; // Indicate error
  }

  int totalDays = 0;

  // Handle cases where start and end month are the same
  if (startMonth == endMonth) {
    totalDays = endDate - startDate + 1;
  } else {
    // Add days from start month
    totalDays += getDaysInMonth(year, startMonth) - startDate + 1;

    // Add days from all months between start and end month (excluding start and end month)
    for (int month = startMonth + 1; month < endMonth; month++) {
      totalDays += getDaysInMonth(year, month);
    }

    // Add days from end month
    totalDays += endDate;
  }

  return totalDays;
}

int main() {
  // Example usage: Calculate days between January 1st and December 31st, 2024 (should be 366)
  int totalDays = countDays(1, 1, 31, 12, 2024);
  printf("Total days between January 1st and December 31st, 2024: %d\n", totalDays);

  // You can call this function with different start and end dates within the same year
  int daysBetween = countDays(10, 5, 20, 8, 2024); // Should be 112
  printf("Total days between May 10th and August 20th, 2024: %d\n", daysBetween);

  return 0;
}



You tried to fetch the 12th element of the month_days list. You used month_days[month] for this but the month variable is 12 and the last index of month_days list is 11. So you should use month_days[month-1] instead. The output you saw is just a random digit since it was out of index.
